# Intel HD Graphics 530 blinking monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display

So I used to have a GTX 1070 but it had issue and it's being repaired atm, in the meantime I'm trying to use my onboard graphics but my monitor keeps blinking, it just goes black for like 2-3 seconds and then goes on and it happens ALOT. I tried several driver reinstalls of several versions, but didn't work.

build:

i7 6700K

MSI Z170A-G43 PLUS

16GB RAM

BenQ XL2430T 24inch

Windows 10 64-Bit

any help appreciated

Comment: Just for a quick check, is your actual physical connection solid? No loose cable to the monitor that keeps sliding in and out? Also try with a new cable as well to rule that out

Comment: no the hdmi cable is firmly in there, even tried with a dvi, still blinking

Comment: What resolution and refresh rate is your monitor?

Comment: 1920*1080@60Hz.